# Wait until valid JSON response is received - Python

Tags: python, json, get

I am currently writing a script that sends a request to a specific webpage and returns a JSON response. The issue is that multiple of the same requests come back, and some are HTML and one is JSON. I've been researching how to keep checking until a valid JSON response is returned, but no luck. Here is what I have currently:

```
response = requests.get('http://www.samplewebpage.com')
inputJSON = json.loads(response.text)
exampleList = list(inputJSON['metaData'].values())
outputArray = []
```

Is there an easy way to loop through the json.loads to wait until the response is a actual JSON?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "multiple of the same request come back"... does that mean you get multiple responses for one request? It doesn't work like that. How do you know you get multiple.

Comment: The website I'm sending the request to is strange and does return multiple responses from the one. I looked in the cookies and headers and they are also identical. It returns 3 responses, two are raw HTML and one is JSON which takes the longest to load.

Answer (score 1):

```
found = False

while not found:
    response = requests.get('URL')
    try:
        inputJSON = json.loads(response.text)
        found = True
        print('valid JSON')
    except:
        print('not valid JSON')
        pass
```